# How can I transform a string into a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I wrote a program that can find the way through a labyrinth. This program works with a matrix.

Now I want to know how I can convert this string:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXIXXX
X                 X
X XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X             X   X
X XXX XXXXX X X X X
X   X X   X X X X X
X X X XXX X X X X X
X X X     X X   X X
XXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXXX
```

into a matrix like this:

```
data = [["X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "I", "X", "X", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", "X"], 
        ["X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "O", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"]]
```

Comment: What have you already tried (Post some code! Explain it!)? What happened (wrong result, error etc.)?

Comment: Is it necessary to convert types from `str` to `list`? Both are iterables and interchangeable in may cases.

Comment: My programm works. Its just this string that i dont know how to convert into a matrix. And i realy have no idea how could i do that for a string that has no fixed size

Comment: @Sven: Your labyrinth program uses a matrix that's a list of lists of strings, with each string being a single cell of the matrix. But myaut is saying that you can instead simply use a list of strings,  with each string being a row of the matrix. And that will require only very minor changes to your code, and possibly no changes at all, depending on how you've written your code.

Comment: It's great that your labyrinth program works, but pureferret is asking you to post some code that attempts to convert the string into a matrix, since that's the topic of your question. Questions without relevant code risk getting closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
[[x for x in line] for line in a.split('\n')]
```

Example:

```
>>> a = """
... XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXIXXX
... X                 X
... X XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
... X             X   X
... X XXX XXXXX X X X X
... X   X X   X X X X X
... X X X XXX X X X X X
... X X X     X X   X X
... XXXXXXXXXXXOXXXXXXX
... """


>>> [[x for x in line] for line in a.split('\n')]
[[], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'I', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X'], ['X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X'], ['X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X'], ['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X'], ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X'], ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], []]
```

And to remove empty sublists:

```
[z for z in ([x for x in line] for line in a.split('\n')) if z]
```

Comment: As jonrsharpe said in his comment on blue_note's answer, `list(line)` is better than `[x for x in line]`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you string is defined as

```
text = '''
X....
'''
```

you get the matrix by

```
matrix = [[str(char) for char in line] for line in text.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Why not just `[list(line) for line in ...]`? It's **already a string**, there's really no point explicitly "converting" each `char` to `str`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: you' re right, I was just in "list comprehension" thinking mode